# List<T> - do I pass objects or references?

Tags: c#, list, generics

Well I have looked into generics and have following question:

```
List<someClass> list=new List<someClass>

SomeClass MyInstance=SomeClass();

list.Add(MyInstance);
```

I am not sure what will be added to list - reference or object of reference type (pointing to actual value of MyInstance).
EDIT: Or I will add value (that is reference data type) which points to actual object?

Thanks

Comment: Classes are always passed as references

Comment: @Skliwz: "Classes are always passed as references" First off, classes aren't passed anywhere. There are objects and, for our purposes (which means I'm hiding some details), they are either instances of value types or instances of reference types. Second, unless a parameter is marked with `ref` or `out` it is PASSED BY VALUE. I'll repeat that: all parameters, unless marked with `ref` or `out` are passed by value, whether or not the parameter is an instance of a value type or an instance of a reference type. For reference types, the value is the reference.

Answer (score 20):

When you deal with reference types you are always dealing with references, so a reference will be added to the list (a copy of the reference actually).  You don't actually have a choice; that's how the language works.

Comment: angren: Also actually the value of reference type will be added to the list. And this value points to object on the heap

Comment: Yes, I said that right here: "a copy of the reference actually"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming someClass is a reference type (e.g. class) and not a value type (e.g. struct) then its a reference.

Also I admit it would be pretty devilish to define a struct with the name someClass

`struct someClass`

And here's the [obligatory link](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) to the Jon Skeet article on parameter passing.

Answer (score 4):

Since `someClass` is a reference type, a reference to `MyInstance` will be copied into the list.

Answer (score 1):

a reference  will be added since `MyInstance` is of reference type

Answer (score -1):

The list will store the reference of the object instead of the object instance.

Actually,the List store value by use array,and array store the reference on the stack and store the object instance on the heap.

Comment: Not correct. The references are stored on the heap. The reference to the `List<>` itself *may* be on the stack, but the references it contains are not.

Answer (score -1):

If you dispose your object like the following

```
MyInstance = null
```

then, you can't read the MyInstance object ,

but you still can read the object in the list,

because you have two references point to the MyInstance ,

In other words,the object has two reference ,

one is

```
SomeClass MyInstance=SomeClass();
```

the other one is be stored in the list,

and you just dispose one of them,

so you still can read the list[0]

Comment: The question was whether or not there was a reference or a value in the list, the answer is *reference*, as is already answered.

Comment: Setting a variable to `null` is *not* 'disposing'.