# How to preserve lists already created before using List.Clear()

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I add data to a `List`, then append that list to another list, then use `List.Clear()` on the original list, it empties everything and the lists already appended aren't preserved.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. Lets say I make 2 lists like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> list2 = new List<List<int>>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

  for(int i2=0;i2<10;i2++){
    list.Add(i2);
  }
  list2.Add(list);
  list.Clear();

}
```

When I run `list.Clear()` it clears out all of the pre-existing lists I already appended to `list2`

I know a work-around would be to re-arrange the code like this:

```
List<List<int>> list2 = new List<List<int>>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

  List<int> list = new List<int>(); //<- moved inside the for

  for(int i2=0;i2<10;i2++){
    list.Add(i2);
  }
  list2.Add(list);

}
```

But is this normal behavior?  Is it possible to preserve the pre-appended lists?

Comment: Seems like you want to copy the list. You can easily use `.ToList()` to create a new list with the same elements.

Comment: Well I don't want to copy the list, its different data each time. My example just tries to explain the situation

Comment: Actually, just don't do `list.Clear()`, because you're creating a new list each iteration anyways. So why are you clearing the current one?

Comment: @YoryeNathan In the 2nd codeblock its creating a new list, but I want to avoid this route.  In the 1st code block, it is not creating a new list, but adding to the same list, then clearing it.

Comment: In the 2nd block of code, you're creating a new list and eventually clearing it for no reason. You will HAVE to create new lists, because you HAVE new lists.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yes you're right, copy/paste mistake,ignore that. I updated it.

Comment: It kind of looks like you already understand the answer to your problem with the work around you posted. If you want to preserve pre-appended lists just don't clear the pre-appended list that you created or create a new list and assign it to that.

Comment: @NFaneDev Right, but when I hit .clear it shouldn't affect any pre-made lists I used that same variable for and sent them off to another variable.  This is unusual behavior like no other language I've worked with.  I don't see why a new list has to be created on each iteration, Wondering why it's not reusable

Comment: JS example: var m = [1,2,3]; var n = [m]; m.length=0; console.log(n);

Comment: `list2` is a list of _lists_. When you `list2.Add(list)` you are adding a _reference_ to `list` to the contents of `list2`. Any changes subsequently made to `list` will be apparent no matter how you access it, e.g. by looking at it through `list` or `list2[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes are passed by reference and `List<T>` is a class. Accordingly, when you clear list it also clears the data passed by reference in list2. See [List - do I pass objects or references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741160/listt-do-i-pass-objects-or-references) for more details.

This should solve the issue shown in your example and create a new copy of `list` to add to `list2` before clearing `list`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> list2 = new List<List<int>>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

  for(int i2=0;i2<10;i2++){
    list.Add(i2);
  }
  list2.Add(list.ToList()); //modified to create a new List when adding
  list.Clear();

}
```

See also Jon Skeet's [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) for some broader information on how parameters are passed in C#, especially relating to reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Your work-around isn't a work-around; that's the right way to do it.

List is an object and therefore a reference type.  Your `list` is a list of integer *values*; your `list2` is a list of *references to lists of integers*.

Calling `list.ToList()` works because that method returns a new list.  From the source:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

Here's a bit of code to illustrate the difference between a list of **value types** and a list of **reference types**:

```
void Main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 1, z = 2;

    var list = new List<int> { x, y, z };
    list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    x = y = z = 0;
    list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    WorseInt a = new WorseInt { Value = 0 },
        b = new WorseInt { Value = 1 },
        c = new WorseInt { Value = 2 };

    var worseList = new List<WorseInt> { a, b, c };
    worseList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));

    a.Value = b.Value = c.Value = 0;
    worseList.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Value));
}

public class WorseInt
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
0
0
```