# save List to session already created before using List.Clear()

Tags: c#, list, session

I have a code similar to this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    list.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
foreach (var item in list)
{
    lit.Text += string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", item);
}
Session["VarList"] = list;
ViewState["VarList"] = list;
list.Clear();
```

This might sound like a duplicate to this [How to preserve lists already created before using List.Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903388/how-to-preserve-lists-already-created-before-using-list-clear) but i need to save that list somehow beacuse my list is is being populated on various methods and i am facing outofmemoryexception. My list contains object a class and that class has a list, DataTable and some properties. Any solution will be very much appreciated i just need this functionality of preserving the data and clearing the list.

Comment: If you are facing an OutofMemoryException, you might want to take a few steps back and look for the cause of this

Comment: Probably should rethink your design. As it stands, there is no evident (or sane) reason to reuse the same list instance if you're clearing it between uses anyway.

Comment: what about using a dictionary with key / value pairs?

Comment: I think you should learn a bit more about OO programming.
You have to copy the first list, using ToList() and clear the first one, or don't clear it at all

Comment: @LordTitiKaka lit is a Literal control

Comment: @Unlockedluca will it be saved in session ?

Comment: @J.Steen It's the last hope, i was thinking about any work around or hack to put this to work, It's a really big piece of code behind this and i don't wanna mess with it :(

Comment: @Serv Can you guide a bit more about that ? While i am debugging everything is fine untill i hit this list

Comment: "My list contains object a class and that class has a list, DataTable and some properties." -- If you put this into viewstate, the page size will be real HUGE and it going to take lot of bandwidth and time to move back and forth. You need to revisit the purpose/real need of keeping it in view state.

Comment: @Thangadurai Yes i am aware of that but my question is still there will it be saved in session(regardless of this situation just for knowledge ), Now I know I have to rebuild the whole logic.

Answer (score 0):

Sample for storing a dictionary in session (not direct answer):

```
List<MyObject> Mylist;
MyList = GetObjects(TheDate);
Dictionary<DateTime> myDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime>();
myDictionary[TheDate] = MyList;
Session["DateCollections"] = myDictionary;

Sample for retrieving from session (should have null check to be sure it's there):

Dictionary<DateTime> myDictionary  = (Dictionary<DateTime>) Session["DateCollections"];
```

I hope you can continue with this or at least get some inspiration :)

Comment: thanks for the effort, i can easily do that but i needed to transfer the data from list and clear it, You are not clearing your list. Perhaps i have to rebuild this whole thing